# How to remove text in brackets using a regular expression

Tags: c#, regex

I'm looking for a regular expression which will perform the following:

```
INPUT: User Name (email@address.com)
OUTPUT: User Name
```

What would be the best way to achieve this? Using regular expression to extract the text within the brackets and replacing this and any )( characters?

Answer (score 45):

This should do the job:

```
var input = "User Name (email@address.com)";
var output = Regex.Replace(input, @" ?\(.*?\)", string.Empty);
```

Note the escaping of the `(` and `)` chars so that they aren't recognised as group markers.

Comment: this is great for doing something like "User Name (1), Another User (2), Extra User (3)" into "UserName, Another User, Extra User". Thanks for that.

Answer (score 9):

Did you mean you want the user name output, rather than the email address? For either case, you don't *need* regexes. For example, assuming the input is always well-formed and hence leaving out any error checking,

```
string output = input.Substring(0, input.IndexOf(" ("))
```

will get you the user name. And if you did want the email address, that too is available without resorting to regexes:

```
int n;
string output = input.Substring(n = 1 + input.IndexOf('('),
                                input.IndexOf(')') - n)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm just offering another way to do this, although I would just use regex myself as this is clunky:

```
    string output = input.Split('(')[0].TrimEnd();
```