# Match text outside Parentheses

Tags: c#, regex

I have a string

```
string s = Hello, (L05-#301ME) I am a programmer.
```

I need to extract this to

```
string result = Hello, I am a programmer
```

That mean I need to get all text ouside the parentheses. How can I use RegEx to do this task

Comment: Look at the answers here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1388207/how-to-remove-text-in-brackets-using-a-regular-expression http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1359412/c-sharp-remove-text-in-between-delimiters-in-a-string-regex

Comment: You could replace all pairs of parentheses (along with the content in between) with an empty string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
var input = "Hello, (L05-#301ME) I am a programmer.";
var output = Regex.Replace(input, @" ?\(.*?\)", string.Empty);
Console.WriteLine(output);
// output would be "Hello, I am a programmer."
```