# How to remove the text inside a brackets

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

How to remove the text inside the brackets. When the using type Galaxy s10 into an input tag. It will trigger an autocomplete and display something like this

```
Galaxy s10 (Samsung)
Galaxy s10 Pro (Samsung)
```

So when the user chose the `Galaxy s10 (Samsung)` it will insert into the input tag. How to remove `(Samsung)` before it been passed into the database.

Comment: `yourString = yourString.Replace("(Samsung)", string.Empty).Trim()`?   Won't work for anything but "(Samsung)" though.

Comment: the other option is to get the index for ```(``` in your string and then use ```.Remove(...)``` to pretty much remove all characters from that index onwards.

Comment: Instead of manipulate strings - use object with two values `Name` and `Value`, where `Name = "Galaxy s10 (Samsung)"` and `Value = "Galaxy s10"`. Map name property to display text and map value property to selected value in html.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1388207/how-to-remove-text-in-brackets-using-a-regular-expression

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MD. RAKIB HASAN has provided a nice short answer, but it requires understanding regular expressions, which can be intimidating.

[Link to demo in DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/4awXeW)

Here is an alternative method that only requires understanding two methods:

1. IndexOf
   s. Substring

```cs
    var input = "User Name (email@address.com) (more)";
    var p1 = input.IndexOf("(");
    string output = "";
    var p0 = 0;
    while (p1 >= 0) {
        var p2 = input.IndexOf(")", p1 + 1);
        p0.Dump();
        if (p2 >= 0) {
            output += input.Substring(p0, p1 - p0) + input.Substring(p1 + 1, p2 - p1 - 1);
            p0 = p2 + 1;
            p1 = input.IndexOf("(", p2 + 1);
        }
    }
    
    Console.WriteLine(output);
```

Comment: I wanted to remove the brackets and also the text inside the brackets

Comment: Take a look at the following line of code and see if you can figure-out what it is doing, once you do so, it is easy to adjust: 'output += input.Substring(p0, p1 - p0) + input.Substring(p1 + 1, p2 - p1 - 1);' If you don't understand that line, try writing some of that data to the console to inspect.